# User control child, releasing too late

Tags: c#, wpf, garbage-collection

Using WPF I M not very happy about how Frames and Pages navigate and use memory (for example not being able to delete the navigation forward stack) so I decided to follow a new route using UserControls instead of Pages and a custom UserControl to navigate (setting the Content to the current "page").

But still I am running into a very extrange problem: if I replace the content, the memory of the previous "page" get released after 2 replacements.

This is my very reduced LightNavigationControl (please note there is not real functionality for navigation yet), it simply presents the "page" element on this.Content and force a call on GC to hopefully release the replaced one.

```
public partial class LightNavigationControl : UserControl
{
    public LightNavigationControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

    }

    public void ClearContent()
    {
        this.Content = null;

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }

    public void PutContent()
    {
        this.Content = new CustomPages.MemoryTestPage();

        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        GC.Collect();
    }
```

This is an example of a "page" I am using:

```
public partial class MemoryTestPage : UserControl
{
    public byte[] myMemory = new byte[50*1024*1024];    //allocate 50MB
    public MemoryTestPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

And this is what happens when I call to the Put/Clear Content elements, for example:

```
 Action      |   Memory 
_________________________
PutContent   |   50MB
PutContent   |   100MB
PutContent   |   100MB
PutContent   |   100MB
ClearContent |   50MB
ClearContent |   0MB
```

Removing the GC calls does affect memory, it will keep growing up to 4-5 and then drop to 50 MB sometimes... but it is quite irregular. Any suggestions?

Thanks!

**EDIT 1**

Seems that the cause could be that the GC is firing too soon, so the old "page" has not been unreferenced yet. Calling GC on page_unloaded does not fire (possibly because I am just removing it but should send a special signal?) nor on the new page loaded callback.

Comment: Why are you so worried about the memory usage? Do you have a scenario where this is a problem

Comment: Yes, I am afraid that latter on I need to go to a very-expensive in memory 3D page, and If I run my program in "quite old" computers I can't get all the memory I need. I know this is not a leak or the biggest issue (because I wont have 50MB pages really, but I want to understand it and try to reduce it).

Comment: How do you track memory usage? From where are the values of your "Memory" column?

Comment: I am using an application called ProcessExplorer as used here: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jgoldb/archive/2008/02/04/finding-memory-leaks-in-wpf-based-applications.aspx , see my Edit 1 by the way